# how to make div with one line of text and div with two the same height?

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

How can I make all boxes (box class) the same height so status is in the same line? The text inside boxes need to be vertically aligned. I need something like this (don't worry about the arrows):

[image]

I need to support IE10. I have html and css like this:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
}
.box {
  white-space: pre;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="box">Get parent
folder owner</span>
    <span class="status">PASSED</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="box">Some text</span>
    <span class="status">PASSED</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="box">Some text</span>
    <span class="status">RUNNING</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is no CSS method (including flexbox) for equalising heights between elements that do not share a parent. You would need javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add three last properties:

```
.box {
    white-space: pre;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 9px 0;
    /*add the lines below:*/
    display: table-cell;
    height: 70px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can rearrange the HTML, the solution is to use a table structure.

```css
.thetable {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 10px 0;
}
.boxrow, .statusrow {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: table-row;
}
.boxrow li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: pre;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.statusrow li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="thetable">
  <ul class="boxrow">
    <li>Get parent
folder owner</li>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li>Some text</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="statusrow">
    <li>PASSED</li>
    <li>PASSED</li>
    <li>RUNNING</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```